Flutter module integration with native project
I want add a flutter module into existing iOS and android project. The only two ways i found to do so are through ARR and making a module and adding as a dependency. I want to add the flutter module as a dependency, but do not want to keep it as a local path but documentation in the ruby script on iOS says to add it in Podfile of iOS project as a local path. Is there any way to add the pod for flutter module through a link for github library of flutter module?

It seems the only way is to use a local path.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
